# Extracting quarry sites geographic data from OSM or Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, etl

Does anyone know where or how I can get geographic data for quarry sites for Australian states or local governments? I have searched all over the data repositories hosted by the levels of government.

Now I resorted to extract this data from Openstreetmaps or Google maps API, but I can figure out how to achieve this after trying to check around. All the pointers doesn't seem to yield any data.

How can I get data and specifically quarry sites from OSM or Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

Quarries are [tagged](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in OSM as [landuse=quarry](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:landuse%3Dquarry). For retrieving specific data you can use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). Overpass API has a nice frontend called [overpass turbo](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/).

Here is an example query for retrieving all quarries in Australia:

```
[out:json][timeout:90];
// fetch area “Australia” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Australia}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “landuse=quarry”
  node["landuse"="quarry"](area.searchArea);
  way["landuse"="quarry"](area.searchArea);
  relation["landuse"="quarry"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can [view the result here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/gcp). There are also options for downloading raw data.

Constructing the query is as simple as opening [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/), opening the wizard and typing *"landuse=quarry" in Australia*. Afterwards the *timeout* parameter has to be raised manually since the default timeout of 25 (seconds) is too low for querying such a huge country.

Note that the query language of Overpass API is quite powerful and there are many ways to enhance your query. Also note that it is possible to call Overpass API directly without the need of overpass turbo which is just a nice frontend.

Comment: Thank you guys, let me get down to it.

Comment: This was very helpful marc_s and scai, now I just have to clean the data.